# PHP Session Data for Username/Password

Tags: php, session, post

I created an html file with login inputs:

```
<?php include "http://website.com/login.php"; ?>
<link href="http://website.com/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="contactForm" id="contactForm" style="width: 500px; margin: auto; float: left;">
   <form name="myform" method="post" action="http://website.com/login.php">
     <p class="form" style="width: 245px; height: 116px; margin-right: 10px;"><input class="field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
     <input class="field" type="password" autofocus="" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" />
     <button class="button" name="Submit" >Login</button></p>
   </form>
</div>
```

The username and password is then send to the login.php file, which looks like this:

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     session_start();

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     // username and password are checked
     if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

            // redirect to protected page
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                    header('Status: 303 See Other');
                }
                else {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
                }
            }

       header('Location: downloadarea.php');
       exit;
       }
      }
?>
```

Into the downloadarea.php file, which is actually an html file and just includes an auth.php file, which checkes, if the user is signed in or not. When the user is not signed in, it will redirect to the login html file (not to the login.php).

downloadarea.php:

```
<?php include('auth.php'); ?>
```

auth.php:

```
<?php
     session_start();

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     if (!isset($_SESSION['angemeldet']) || !$_SESSION['angemeldet']) {
      header('Location: website.com/login.html/');
      exit;
      }
?>
```

Ok. Now I want a little message to come up (sort of a red border, or a message, which is displayed beneath my login button). However, I don't know how to do that as the login.php needs to send variables back to login.html where I have my inputs. What code do I need?

Edit: login.php, auth.php and downloadarea.php are not in the same directory as my input-html file

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't send the password like that though.

Comment: I know, I've read so much about it. I'm totally new to PHP, but it's not for a professional homepage

Comment: When should the little message pop up?

Comment: When a wrong password is entered. Sorry, forgot to mention this

Comment: So when the password isn't admin?

Comment: yes, or the username is wrong

Comment: Okay so let me get this straight. You want to show the message on login.php when the login information is wrong on login.php?

Comment: I want to show a little message on login html. The html file is reffering to the login.php

Comment: Why do you have 2 login files? You can just use the html from the login.html and use it into login.php

Comment: Because my website is running on wordpress. I created a blog entry with the html code.

Comment: I just have to insert this code into my html file. But, how is the php file intercommunicating with the html file like sending variables back to the html file?

Comment: The session sends the variables back to the html file. You can also just make another session like: $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; and use that in the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you use login.html to send everything into login.php and then check everything in login.php. After that you want to go back to login.html and show a message when it's wrong.

So what to do is use the session you made in login.html:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['angemeldet'])){
    //Something you want to happen when you are logged in.
}
else{
     echo "Wrong username/password";
}
?>
```

The red border etc should be made in css.

Comment: I will try that. I don't know if Wordpress is able to handle PHP, but let's have a try! Thank you, I'll let you know!!!

Comment: Sorry @Loko, but it's not working. It always redirects me to login.php.

Comment: @fjw you should only redirect in the else. Dont put the redirecting in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

**login.php**

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     session_start();

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     // username and password are checked
     if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

            // redirect to protected page
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                    header('Status: 303 See Other');
                }
                else {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
                }
            }

       header('Location: downloadarea.php');
       exit;
       }
       
        else {
        echo "<div id='session_name'>Wrong credentials</div>";
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#session_name {
font-weight:bold;
color:#0000FF;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color: #FF0000;
background:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Original answer

> *"Now I want a little message to come up (sort of a red border, or a message, which is displayed beneath my login button)"*

Here is a very basic method, using `USER` as the session name:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['angemeldet'] = "USER";
?>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['angemeldet']) || !empty($_SESSION['angemeldet'])) { 
echo "You are logged in." . $_SESSION['angemeldet'];
}
?>

<br><br>
Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['angemeldet']; ?>
```

**And to add styling:** (basic example)

```
<div id="session_name">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['angemeldet']; ?></div>

<style>
#session_name {
font-weight:bold;
color:#0000FF;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color: #FF0000;
background:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The question is very unclear. I've tried to understand it. Read the comments though.

Comment: Will let the OP decide, that's why I highlighted his/her comment in the top of my answer from the question. @Loko

Comment: I'm sorry! I should have given different names

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "different names" part? @user3320275 - This was based on the comment that you wrote in your question *"Now I want a little message to come up (sort of a red border, or a message, which is displayed beneath my login button)"*

Comment: and could have explained it much better than I did!

Comment: Also, my answer's code was to be inserted in the code where you presently have it under "**I created an html file with login inputs**", and you will need to have the filename with `.php` extension for it to work if it's not `.php` yet. @user3320275

Comment: @Fred -ii- I think you got me wrong. When the username and password is sent to the login.php, where it is checked. When user and pw is correct, login.php is redirecting to a different file. But, when one of them is wrong, login.php should send back to the html "hey, not going in because it's a wrong password/username". Then, a little div should be seen. 

But if the solution with only one login page is easer, how do I set up such an page in PHP with if and else condition?

Comment: Ok, reload this page/answer and look under the **EDIT** (login.php) @fjw

Comment: @Fred-ii-, **+1** for the collossal answer mate ! Seems like you opened your can of worms rofl !

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran LOL, indeed I have! Thanks Shankar, I hope you are well my dear friend :-) Peace my brother

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am well and I hope you are too ! :)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yes thanks Shankar. Spring is on its way, winter is almost over too! :-) cheers!